# openssl update on ubuntu 8.04

Tags: openssl, 8.04, tls

I have an old e-commerce website on an old but stable Ubuntu 8.04.

We're worried about the new OpenSSL requirement for Paypal. Seems that we have to update the TLS protocol to version 1.2 and actually we've the `0.9.8k-7ubuntu8.27` version installed.

Do we need to upgrade even if the website doesn't run in SSL mode? If yes, is there any chance to do it without dist-upgrade?

Comment: Oh my god, 8.04. 14.04 is quite stable, I'd say use it.

Comment: I know this is not what you want to hear - but: You should upgrade from 8.04, as there's probably many more security vulnerabilities in an 8 year old version than just the outdated openssl. IMO, you should get / migrate to something newer ASAP, _especially for an ecommerce website_.

Comment: I'm surprised 8.04 still runs. It's APT repos were gone, I think. Also, you can't `dist-upgrade` from 8.04, your only option is fresh-install a newer version.

Comment: @BharadwajRaju You can still use Ubuntu without APT repos, although in this case, they still exist.

Comment: @JonasCz The 8.04 mirrors are still up? Wow.

Comment: what about compiling new openssl?

Comment: Aren't questions related to 8.04 considered off-topic?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I'm sorry but you asking a question about an Ubuntu distribution which has reached already its end of lifetime. You might want to consider upgrading. I'm voting to close the question therefore as off-topic because its about an EOL release of Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query *Do we need to upgrade even if the website doesn't run in SSL mode?* suggests that you are not using SSL/TLS for your client connections but as you are connecting to PayPal servers you need to initiate TLS connections at that point.

[PayPal have stated](https://www.paypal-knowledge.com/infocenter/index?page=content&widgetview=true&id=FAQ1914&viewlocale=en_US) that as of June 2017 they will not accept API connections using anything other than TLS 1.2. This means you need to upgrade somehow, as TLS 1.2 support wasn't added to OpenSSL until v1.0.1 and this version wasn't packaged for your version of Ubuntu.

You have two options - upgrade the whole server or compile your own OpenSSL. I would highly recommend going for the first option as that leaves the complex and repetitive task of patching and testing OpenSSL to Ubuntu packagers; something I'm sure you haven't the time or inclination to do on a production server.

Comment: ok, so the first version using openssl 1.0.1 is 12.04, isn't it?

Comment: I believe that's correct, but 12.04.5 LTS becomes EOL in less than a year. 14.04 LTS is EOL 2019 and 16.04 LTS in 2021.